# Side Navigation always open/open on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I know this might sound simple to some of you, but I'm a beginner and I'm trying to tackle JS.

Anyway, I have a html, css, jquery sidebar I want to edit so it doesn't open/close onclick. 
Instead I want it to open (and stay opened) when the page loads. 
But I have no idea how to do this. I've looked everywhere, but couldn't find an answer. Maybe I just don't know what exactly I should be looking for.

Someone, please help. And please make it as simple as possible because, like I said, I'm a beginner and this is all still very confusing to me.
Thank you.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; </a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
```

Comment: Remove the following lines from your HTML:`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; </a>` and `<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>`. Alternately, if you want to still have those display (not a good idea from a user interface point of view) remove `onclick="closeNav()"` and `onclick="openNav()"`. You may want to change `<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >` to `<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="width:200px;">`

Comment: This worked perfectly! And it's so simple. Thank you so much, Makyen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following lines from your HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; </a>
```

and

```
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
```

Alternately, if you want to still have those display (not a good idea from a user interface point of view) remove `onclick="closeNav()"` and `onclick="openNav()"`.

In addition, you may want to change

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
```

to

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="width:200px;">
```

Comment: Yup, just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `openNav` at the bottom of your script.

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" >
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times; </a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function openNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
}

function closeNav() {
 document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
  
openNav()
</script>
```

Comment: This does the job, too. Thank you, Red Mercury! I've gave it an upvote, but my rep is below 15 so it won't show apparently!

Comment: While this will have it open upon load, it does not cover the OP's request that it not be able to be opened/closed upon clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it will always open on page load. One quick but dirty trick is to make make its width zero when its opens on page load, and another width, lets say 400px when the button is clicked. Just go to the very first line of your HTML code and change this:
`<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">`
to

`<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style= "width:0px;">`